# How to DRY up Webhook handlers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been developing Stripe Webhook handler to create/update records depending the values.

It's not really hard, if it's a simple like this below;

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|

      events.subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
        charge = event.data.object
        StripeMailer.receipt(charge).deliver
        StripeMailer.admin_charge_succeeded(charge).deliver
      end
    end
```

However If I need to store the data conditionally, it could be little messier.
In here I extracted the each Webhook handler and defined something like `stripe_handlers/blahblah_handler.rb`.

```
class InvoicePaymentFailed
      def call(event)
        invoice_obj = event.data.object
        charge_obj = retrieve_charge_obj_of(invoice_obj)
        invoice = Invoice.find_by(stripe_invoice_id: charge_obj[:invoice])

        # common execution for subscription
        invoice.account.subscription.renew_billing_period(start_at: invoice_obj[:period_start], end_at: invoice_obj[:period_end])

        case invoice.state
        when 'pending'
          invoice.fail!(:processing,
                        amount_due: invoice[:amount_due],
                        error: {
                          code: charge_obj[:failure_code],
                          message: charge_obj[:failure_message]
                        })
        when 'past_due'
          invoice.failed_final_attempt!
        end

        invoice.next_attempt_at = Utils.unix_time_to_utc(invoice_obj[:next_payment_attempt].to_i)
        invoice.attempt_count = invoice_obj[:attempt_count].to_i
        invoice.save
      end


      private

      def retrieve_charge_obj_of(invoice)
        charge_obj = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(id: invoice.charge)
        return charge_obj
      rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError, Stripe::AuthenticationError, Stripe::APIConnectionError, Stripe::StripeError => e
        logger.error e
        logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      end
    end
end
```

I just wonder how I can DRY up this Webhook handler.

Is there some best practice to approach this or any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring working code are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suggest re-raising the exception in `retrieve_charge_obj_of`, since you'll just get a `nil` reference exception later on, which is misleading. (As is, you might as well let the exception bubble up, and let a dedicated error handling system rescue, log, and return a meaningful `500` error.)

   a. If you *don't* want to return a 500, then you have a bug b/c `retrieve_charge_obj_of` *will return nil after the exception is rescued*. And if `charge_obj` is `nil`, then this service will raise a NPE, resulting in a 500.
2. if `invoice_obj[:next_payment_attempt]` can be `!present?` (`blank?`), then what is `Utils.unix_time_to_utc(invoice_obj[:next_payment_attempt].to_i)` supposed to mean?

   a. If it was `nil`, `false`, or `''`, `#to_i` returns `0` -- is that intended? (`[]`/`{}` is also `blank?` but would raise)

Conceptually, this handler needs to issue a state transition on an `Invoice`, so a chunk of this logic can go in the model instead:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  # this method is "internal" to your application, so incoming params should be already "clean"
  def mark_payment_failed!(err_code, err_msg, attempt_count, next_payment_at)
    transaction do # payment processing usually needs to be transactional
      case self.state
      when 'pending'
        err = { code: err_code, message: err_msg }
        self.fail!(:processing, amount_due: self.amount_due, error: err)
      when 'past_due'
        self.failed_final_attempt!
      else
        ex_msg = "some useful data #{state} #{err_code}"
        raise InvalidStateTransition, ex_msg
      end

      self.next_attempt_at = next_payment_at
      self.attempt_count = attempt_count
      self.save
    end
  end

  class InvalidStateTransition < StandardError; end
end
```

Note: I recommend a formal state machine implementation (e.g. [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)) before states & transitions get out of hand.

Data extraction, validation, and conversion should happen in the handler (that's what "handlers" are for), and they should happen before flowing deeper in your application. Errors are best caught early and execution stopped early, before any action has been taken.

There are still some other edge cases that I see that aren't really handled.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For 1, yes I agree. Stripe retries the webhook if the response is non-4xx. However it would be better to request Stripe API explicitly. For 2, Utils.unix_time_utc method is utility method which converts the unix time to utc datetime.

Comment: I think you've missed the most important points of both my comments. I've added some details, please take another look.

Comment: Thanks again. For 1,  you mean if `retrieve_charge_obj_of` returns `nil`, I could re raise an exception? For 2, that's my mistake.  `invoice_obj[:next_payment_attempt]` is always filled if `charge_obj` exists.

Comment: Last update. Not so much to make DRY as there is to rearrange to better separate responsibilities of different parts of code (i.e. design).

Comment: Thanks again. Yea I agree. Putting those methods into Invoce model, it's more cleaner. But I wonder what is 'There are still some other edge cases that I see that aren't really handled.'